# Bootstrap navbar unable to toggle

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

hope you are doing well, I am following Traversy media's Youtube tutorial on bootstrap 5 and when i've tried to get the nav toggler to open but the nav is not showing. i'm not sure what I am doing wrong

This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4sosXZsdy-s the navbar section time stamp is 6:45 to 14:06

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5 libraries -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<!--navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Frontend bootcamp</a>

    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto" id="navbar">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#learn" class="nav-link">What you'll learn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#questions" class="nav-link">Questions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#instructors" class="nav-link">Instructors</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: the script tag is not JS, it is a tag that needs to be included into the ehad element and will load the CSS via JS through external resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have a working example. I did take the `<button>` element from  [bootstraps example](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navbar/) and moved `id="navbar"` from `<ul>` to `<div>` element.

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5 libraries -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.3.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>



<!--navbar-->
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-dark navbar-dark py-3 fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Frontend bootcamp</a>

<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
      <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto" >
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#learn" class="nav-link">What you'll learn</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#questions" class="nav-link">Questions</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#instructors" class="nav-link">Instructors</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thank you for helping, I previously had ID in the div and I still couldn't get it too work and thought i'd try in the ul.